# Use Mailto with a large set of emails

Tags: html, mailto

On a page I have, there is a piece of code that creates a mailto link for the members of a team. It just iterates through the list of members and dynamically creates the link

My problem is that when the number of members grows, it eventually stops the mailto link from working. I believe there is a character limit on this function, with the actually character limit depending on browser maybe.

I'm wondering is there any elegant solution or alternative to this?

Sending the email from the server side is not really an option, users still want to use their own desktop email app.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be have the mailto send to a single email address that then auto forwards the message to all required individual emails.

Comment: Not really an option, the team(s) can be changed on the fly and everytime they do the auto forward would need to be getting changed too, and this app has no way of doing that.